# Checking whether insertion of new row in mySql database was successful using php, and returning the newly inserted row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php code that registers new users from my android app. I have declared the username field as unique, so if a duplicate username is entered it will generate error at insertion. How do i check whether the insertion was executed succesfully and how do i proceed with returning the newly added row to the app. Here is my code, what should i write in the if() statement?

```
$con = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$imagelink = $_POST["imagelink"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$dob = $_POST["dob"];
$mobile = $_POST["mobile"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$currency = $_POST["currency"];
$location = $_POST["location"];


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO a8768135_testdb.Uzer (username, password, imagelink, name, dob, mobile, email, currency, location) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssssssss", $username, $password, $imagelink, $name, $dob, $mobile, $email, $currency, $location);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);


if() {
    $statemente = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM a8768135_testdb.Uzer WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statemente, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statemente);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statemente);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statemente, $userID, $username, $password, $imagelink, $name, $dob, $mobile, $email, $currency, $location);

    $user = array();

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($statemente)) {
        $user["username"] = $username;
        $user["password"] = $password;
        $user["imagelink"] = $imagelink;
        $user["name"] = $name;
        $user["dob"] = $dob;
        $user["mobile"] = $mobile;
        $user["email"] = $email;
        $user["currency"] = $currency;
        $user["location"] = $location;
    }

    echo json_encode($user);
}


mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `android`

Comment: read the complete post, in second part i have asked how to return the values in newly added row to my app.

Comment: Does it really make changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php):

```
mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

The result will be the last id (Auto Increment Value) for the record that was just created, a return of value zero means that no new record was added/inserted

Your code should look like this:

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO a8768135_testdb.Uzer (username, password, imagelink, name, dob, mobile, email, currency, location) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssssssss", $username, $password, $imagelink, $name, $dob, $mobile, $email, $currency, $location);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

if(mysqli_insert_id($con) > 0) {
......
}
```

Comment: can u point out the changes i'll have to make? i am not much familiar with php, just using it to store data in mysql database for my android app